# How to view an gif image through PHP GET request?

Tags: php, get

GET Request:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Content-type: image/gif" .
      "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://api.solvemedia.com/papi/media?c=2@o-mubMTi7BBM98cMxgtIcLP4k1Ga5QJl@XmSqPdjlX-EENU8bgrS8i39APTC4lJjob8CffjsxV9jrIPX3GtuHidRkFAj1t048X4InDBGooKrfHCJw-UPc3RJpBQsHb2I4Ug4VdDwqVA6LkWJh3SQOW.xtxmxeN9pNZ1mEbLs-u3qV.Yggw0lLbut2o9pohrFf1j5Fdnw9hpKzSHxwwUck66zMZZv2-NaZh-D.wUNr5e6dWFspNlf-cGlixcH0GFCAtKyRSgVedyp15hlmTgWmuzlcfHwctVjdNqQUiVaxLDqzNsw71YyJ.aFCS7qjn4ZyJkhFXIK0uoAv0iP9---rdedIcIWDMcOAiIpU.IBN8Fs";
$image = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $image;
```

The picture appears like this:

```
GIF87a,–¡ÿÿÿÿÈÈÈ,,–þœ9Àí”<°¶9­ÅRW®x˜ˆ‰˜J©k¸/LÊlÓ9.ë=ïò*a‘Ú±”(fí·„6¥ÏaÔ:Å" ‚5ùå8ÁZòñzÎ¦«k³i‹èvcaÌX\Ïä;ûP¿ôçU†7#×R¨—È·è×ø(ØF8iˆX‰270wgÉàzBôV*bdŠ¦ªÆÊæê† ÇyÐyI*:rê‘*»úÛü:ÛË«1;·¼pÛœ{-P~@~n0ÚîÞ@"ÿî>ŸŽ ~KùïS&F„tPÂ¦…ã"Ì3·nßºxðàµ“ˆ¡"(þ|ÑEôhŽã5€ÅHŽPQBL)9,¬Õ¢Ì‡5Ú#¥/£®vhb¬éIeKƒC•t”eI›hÁ4jæ:ymBU•ÕQAIðY5(Á¤¸V–%ûÌlZ´\0P5«ÌVyŠúùµgÏ¯»žºðß± &ZXa‚¦ÞŠˆ[3ïÆñÐùTà73_~³IóL ´5ÑØ¶}6Í¢iÇ Ïåg9×zó m÷ÁåØ4;£ý»t·ÓÃC7Iš¨€åÌ›3'þÍxqàÓ…G§~Ý:)èÛ¥gGnc…·îØÉkÏ½wóà«·ÿŽ2±Ñðð'x~~¤òþùïWúßYýxŸ}ôÍÞã©Wƒç)˜ ‚ë9ø{øhØ6á„r¸áƒ!VHá…Ç™èŠõe¨¡/®5 €/Š…ØŒÎÐ¨†5jxC„=z8¢Š˜"‘+îx¢‘C²X$“ô¹¨cŽI:¹$’MZy¤”Wj™¥QzÙâ‚Šø#ˆe’ å”XVÉ%›`nùæ“b©d‰uŽI"žBÚI%ŸkúÙ& q†—&œª¨žwÒÙ§¢2ú§£‘Bšh$‡*ã——v¹©› ú©¤•ž™'¥ƒâxª¨©š*«™"º*©{ªÚª¬‹Úú¨Z¨ÖZ(§¯b £–þêk°šKþèœ¸Nºì¨½zŠ,¨ÑÒ:­«ÆÂZ+Z»VÛl¬ÏJ{-°Û†[ì¸ÚÞˆî°äB».¸æ¦««3f~Km»õ¾«.¾ñæ+/šÊÒk­¾çòKð¾jÍûoÂ>Ü-¯ Ù0·³ÜÊpÅ#¼ðÅþf<±³—±½Ã;°Á%³µ1Äs¬òÇ³Ž\0Ê ¯Ü2Ë×ŒóÍ:w,rÈÇØ3Í;Ïì2Å<{[t®B§<ôË>“tÓFÛÌtÕDS}uÎ<ÿ,¬É@s}lÐI3{4ÒX;½tÖR+=¶Çe‹}öÔZ«m5Úm›]6ØØJ|·Ãq³ý7ÙoÃ=·Ý»]¸ÜkNwã†'8äŒKþŽ¸™' u×—kŽyÌóènæaë-®è{¾ø¨›nzéžs;ë¯ó˜öã©ã}»ß”ãNæê§“^nëÁÏþ»ðÉÎ»ãŠ×½¼ò‘[þ¹ï®{{ñÄO/½œÈëž;ßÛ{¿;÷½GO~õØ—/;õég|øàw:óÏË?9ôæ¯¾õùŸ?»À·¿ÿ…îzøcß÷§=÷ÅÏyõ£_å˜<§ð^Æ;àa†@ÿUpƒ¼àÓ¨AZ}#ì_ ×GBþ¡Ð„TW9øÁžP¬Ý,ØBæ°†}{{¸@ÛýÐ‡|`#xCÚp~G_‰(ÄŽá°ƒ),`þC¨C*¾è…"Üág¨B~±^\Ìbyø½ 6/Š›âÇ¨ÅÊQŒ,´VÑ¨@7.±OÌ£¨G@þñmLc!ýØÅ8žîŽp|c9Ç0J²XŒ|äÈÆ5j’‰m$"ÍxI$rr“[8d%#iEK ò¦¢G K>f2–ªkd(8KY’“»ŒOIGTbñ—®]*… Æcs™“f#‰ÙÇVFÓ“À<Ð-¡ØK\f›´%³ ™K^vS›ãä¦.sÎm¾òœìg;½YKU’šÅ¤ç4éEy~2å\§;ã‰Ì|T‘ÍL¦3õi¿B’™Ê,¨@þzP…òóä¤¨9ÿ ÏŒfË–«eG'ŠÑ"´ž‰\¨C ÚÐ”¤gI¯éÏAÁTšáÔèEmÓŠ"¦êäi?}jÑ}rÔ¥-êH¥hÏšê§@ éM?:T£*t¦IMâK¡zT¥>u«9%*H™ZÕŸ†µ”cujWÏÚT°º¥_]ª[¹šÖ·J¢­ëCOjR•‚«šz½k_QQºú•]| ,^©zU¯F­Q-¬]ûØ¼–±YíiYÕZÔ£Å®—•ëfÏêØÁF±™¥l”>‹ÚÎr6±këjK{OØjµg®E«jmËÚÐæÖ´‚…¬hëÛàÊÖ²»mmÝþxÜÛ¦¶¸³Åçh±:UèöV²‘M.s‰;\±–ÔºÙ êr»Ðé’–»ämìø*«]ðb¶¼dot‹^ïÂÐ½â•îaíûWõzV¹ü½.:Ík\7·¿f¤ï}áûÞ¹6s¼Æ®óSÝR¸.ƒã»S?Ø°ÆïdŒáõ68½µ•ð…lbï•·Vp‡\_BjxÄòõoÆâ»˜Ã<~nSãyÇ+1ŠsÜc Ÿx‘Hö1‘•¬b(ËØÆfýî†¬Ù‡x¿Tñ›,å'[8Êcž²~_{å09Ë]æò™qûfY™ÆUÖò‘A–æ2‹¹Â|^²5ÉÜ!g@ûYÇ ñžd=K8Ï2¡Á,\F#Ënôz ;
```

How do I arrange this encoding? To make it a captcha picture

Comment: Seeing this in my browser:{"ACChallengeResult": {
    "chid"     : "",
    "uid"      : "",
    "lang"     : "en",
    "mediatype": "",
    "media_url": "",
    "widget"   : {  "config": null,
                    "pixel":  null,
                    "player": null,
                    "tpdcp":  null  },
    "fail"     : "invalid ckey",
    "helpme"   : 0,
    "clientip" : "104.225.232.127",
    "timestamp": 1515316417,
    "bestuid"  : "",
    "media_size": { "h" : null,
                    "w" : null },
    "chres": {"result":{}}
  }
}

Comment: @Phil hide your ip ^^ i will update the post with valid captcha url and try, one moment

Comment: @Phil i just update the url part. you can try now please? its valid for few minutes

Comment: Will add `header('Content-type: image/gif');` as the first line help? I saw media error gif.

Comment: @Phil Yes, I tried. It did not work but I would try again right away + ino answer

Comment: @Phil Thanks a lot, now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the source of the image right to the browser, and the browser shows what you send.

To appear as an image you have to use HTML tag `IMG` with attributes.

In your case you need to use the base64 coding function [base64_encode() — Encodes data with MIME base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

So do encode the image first:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'. $image .'">';
```